# Use update statement by function SQLExecDirect in ODBC . The attribute could not be successfully modified but was set to null

Tags: c++, mysql, odbc

The GTask attribute of the table stuGroup has not been modified, but has become NULL. I suspect that the wordTask was not successfully passed into the data source, but both SQLBINDPARAMETER and SQLExecDirect were successfully executed.

```
cout << "-------" << "UPDATE" << "-------" << endl;
SQLCloseCursor(hStmt);
SQLLEN wordTask = 100, wordTaskInd = SQL_IS_INTEGER;
cout<<"Please input the task to be assigned: ";
cin >> wordTask;
ret = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &wordTask, 
sizeof(int), &wordTaskInd); // return SQL_SUCCESS
Test(ret, hStmt); // succcessful
ret = SQLExecDirect(hStmt, (SQLCHAR*)"UPDATE stuGroup SET GTask = ?",SQL_NTS); // wordTask may not passed into Datasource ,return SQL_SUCCESS
Test(ret, hStmt); // successful
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add some context and explain what problems you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED：
The StrLen_or_Ind parameter of the SQLBindParameter() function is modified to 0，For detailed reasons, please refer to [Using Length and Indicator Values]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/using-length-and-indicator-values?view=sql-server-ver16